# Will playing the Torgue slots yield me a net benefit?

Tags: borderlands-2

Since the Torgue slots in the Mr. Torgue DLC cost rare Torgue Tokens, I'm wondering if my expected value for them is above zero; e.g. if I play a million times, statistically am I likely to have more or less Torgue Tokens than when I started with? I know I'll get guns and stuff, but the net Torgue Tokens are all I care about; they're annoying to come by and can be used to buy legendary weapons. It costs 5 tokens to play and, from my limited experience, doesn't seem to give a very high payout.

Comment: From my limited experience playing them, I haven't seen them as useful.  Cash is cheap, Torgue tokens, not so much.

Comment: @MBraedley yeah, short-term it definitely doesn't look great. But I'm wondering if maybe the higher payouts make Expected Value positive or not. If they're as crazy rare as the normal slots' payouts...doubtful.

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE I DIDN'T SPELL TORGUE PROPERLY. I MUST HAVE BEEN TOO BUSY THINKING ABOUT EXPLOSIONS AND S***

Comment: Yeah, and at least you can potentially break even with the cash slots by selling whatever you win.

Answer (score 3):

Good sir, from 50+ goes on them, the Torgue slots appear to have the same probabilities as the cash slots with the added disadvantage that useless gear cannot be sold for Torgue Tokens so, do not make the same mistake we did. Save your Torgue tokens for legendaries.

Comment: That was my impression too. Given the [standard slot probabilities](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Moxxi_Slot_Machines_Odds_Probabilities_Statistics) the frequency of TT payouts would be crazy low. Did you happen to notice if you get the same  amount of tokens as you would eridium at the normal slots (4x4, 8x4, 24x4?)

Answer (score 3):

If possible play them with another person. Its a lot better and you hit jackpots a lot more often. My cousin and i played it for like 5 hours last night (we're addicted) and he hit the triple eridium twice i hit it once. He hit marcus heads once too. Overall we went from having around 40 tokens to about 350.

Comment: Also, just like with the regular slot machines, all players receive a copy of the winnings while you pay to play individually. Together with the increased odds of winning, this makes the machines far more profitable when playing in a group.

Answer (score 2):

By yourself no, with four players we were earning about 1000 tokens an hour per player.