# How can I get lots of Torgue Tokens?

Tags: borderlands-2

Best I can tell the [slot machines are a poor way to get Torgue Tokens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94153/will-playing-the-torgue-slots-yield-me-a-net-benefit) due to the high cost and infrequent payouts. Normal enemies rarely drop them. There's some re-doable quests (I think they give torgue tokens anyway) and the super boss Pyro Pete also gives them I believe.

Bottom line, I want some of those Legendary Torgue guns in the Torgue Token vending machine. **How can I get Torgue Tokens in the most efficient manner?** I'm level 50 so beating Pyro Pete the Invincible is possible but...hard. If he drops them in Playthrough 1 I'm wondering if that's a better idea; I hear he's easier in playthrough 1 but I'm not sure he still drops (as many) Torgue Tokens.

Comment: i haven't gotten this far but in my previous experience with Borderlands is more players=more loot.

Comment: @Paralytic good point, but I don't think I know any (active) players who have the Torgue DLC

Comment: you can always join a steam grp if you play this on PC.

Comment: Or you can use a hack that makes your solo game four-player hard: http://myborderlands.com/FourPlayers.aspx

Comment: @OrcJMR I had that actually! I should try it again

Answer (score 7):

It seems like, throughout the internet, there are three main options.  The three options are the **Ballroom Blitz** (Pyro Pete's Bar), the **Race** (Tier 3), or Slot Machines.

Here's a video explaining the Ballroom Blitz:

Essentially, from what I found from the [GameFaq](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638785-borderlands-2/64742805) forums:

> Bar room ball. Tested and it's faster. The quickest I was able to get
>   20 from the race was 80 seconds or so. 1:45 to finish the race and I
>   had something like 20 seconds left over. Bar room brawl on the other
>   hand, you get 2:30 (I think) and the fastest I was able to do that was
>   in 45 seconds. The trick is to stay in two areas. The Badasses only
>   appear to spawn upstairs and out of the top right door on the bottom
>   level (according to your map) so all I do is stay close to that
>   staircase and travel up and down between floors. Never have I failed
>   to kill them all this way and usually it's in under a minute.

On the other hand though, you can try doing the races to gain tokens.  It's a lot simpler if you have [Afterburner](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Afterburner) relics with you.

Also taken from the GameFaq Forums:

> Bar Brawl is faster ... but I HATE that I lose money there. Every
>   session at least one or two rats seem to get away and stash my money,
>   grrrr.
>
> So I just used the Tier 3 Death Race with an Afterburner relic. Only
>   slightly slower, but no irritating money loss.

Note that with the option of doing the races, you will have no rats taking your hard-earned Torgue Tokens, and you'll get a guaranteed 20 tokens upon winning.

Comment: A use for the afterburner relic? WHAT IS THIS MADNESS

Comment: I know right?  Apparently you need it to start the missions (Disclaimer: I don't have the DLC)

Comment: Oh, no, you don't need it to do these missions, it would just be helpful. The racing mission is pretty easy without it, there are no enemies or anything, fixed track. It's...really boring honestly.

Comment: The Bar Brawl rats are gone with [the latest hot fix](http://www.trueachievements.com/n12117/hot-fixes-coming-to-borderlands-2.htm)

Comment: race is kinda hard if you don't have the afterburner and the max mistakes you can make in it is 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

Max out your cool-down rate & your action skill duration on Commando or Gunzerker then... for Commando, longbow turret upstairs after about 10 seconds of fighting downstairs... then run to the back room & get busy... helps if you have high powered homing EOT grenades too! for Gunzerker, Gunzerk & start in the back room going upstairs & throwing x2 grenades downstairs repeatedly... keep killing... they will stop spawning after about 3 minutes & you can quickly collect tons of tokens! then go outside & do it again!

Comment: EOT?12345679801

Answer (score 0):

Have another account with tokens and player 1 sends tokens at slots while player 2 gets free tokens. Can be done in reverse.

Comment: I did my best to decipher what was said here. Still doesn't seem to make much sense, so clarifications would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Death Race, best to use the barrel flingging jeep. Seems slower but the boost last longer and charges quicker, so can be done without that Atferburner Relic...still a pain in the arse, though.